# How i can use variable inside javascript match function

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I'm trying to use variable inside regex match function but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
var text = "jon";
Persons.match('/<tr><td>(.*?)'+ text +'(.*?)<\/tr>/g');
```

I have also try it:

```
Persons.match(/<tr><td>(.*?)text(.*?)<\/tr>/g);
```

it's consider text as a string not a variable.

Comment: Use `new RegExp(...)`

Comment: how i can use it with my code can you explain little bit

Comment: and this question is not duplication it's with different function